# Why is java VMware unexpectedly shutting down or crash my android app ? (PID 22678)

Tags: java, android, firebase, sdk, vmware

I am doing A java android studio app and it gave me a runtime error. I tried many ways and couldn't reach the answer and needed help.
This is the error message that I am suffering.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqFul.png)

These are the dependencies I am using:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.hitranslatorapp'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.hitranslatorapp"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language:22.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language-language-id-model:20.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-natural-language-translate-model:20.0.8'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.4.1')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with VMWare.  I'm not sure why you think it does, but this is a standard ANdroid crash.

NoSuchMethodError means the method doesn't exist.  It can occur because of reflection with a bad method name (or broken due to proguard), or because something goes wrong at the linking stage and you link against an older or newer library version than you compile against and the method/class has changed signatures.  Generally that occurs due to different modules of the app requiring different library versions and one overriding the other.  What's happening here is impossible to tell further from what you've posted.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll follow it.